# How much % rise can one ask during conversion from contract to permanent?

Tags: salary, negotiation, contracts

I am working as a contractor for the past 3 months now and when I accepted this role I settled with the pay which I later realized is much less when compared with others in the industry. I still have 9 more months in my contract period but I am being offered a permanent role in the same company. The amount which I have quoted is near to 40% more than what I am getting now.The HR told that he will give me an offer that matches the industry standard. When getting converted from contractor to permanent role, how much % rise can one expect?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this isn't a raise.  You can simply treat it as a position negotiation.

Comment: VTC advice question. There's no set number, whatever number we give won't apply to your specific situation anyway. It's just too dependent on your situation and profile. General tips may be available on [freelancing.se].

Comment: Often you get less when converting to a permanent position because they have to pay the cost of benefits. Expecting a 40% raise is probably unrealistic in almost any company. I have never even known anyone below the VP level to get that kind of raise even with a promotion. To do the same work?

Answer (score 7):

Normally a contractor makes much more than a permanent staff member, because they take a lot of risks and cover their own overheads. So if you're getting a rise, then you were charging too little as a contractor. Despite what people may say, there is no set norm for a contractor, you can charge as much as the market will bear.

My suggestion is you find out what is the industry norm for a full time permanent staff member in a similar position and ask for that. And forget trying to work it out as a percentage of what you made as a contractor.

Comment: He might actually be contracted through some kind of employment firm and can't set his own prices.